Theorem 19.5 from Matsumura's Commutative ring theory, case $A[[ X ]]$.
So on page 157 of Matsumura's "Commutative ring theory", theorem 19.5, to prove "If $A$ is regular then so is $A[[X]]$" it is mentioned that
"Now although we cannot say that $B_M$ contains $A_{\mathfrak{m}}[[X]]$, but the two have the same completion, $\widehat{B_M} = \widehat{A_{\mathfrak{m}}}[[X]]$."
Here $A$ is a regular ring, $B= A[[ X ]]$, $M$ is any maixmal ideal of $B$, and $\mathfrak{m} = M\cap A$ a maximal ideal of $A$. The above completion refers to $M-$ (resp. $\mathfrak{m}-$) adic completion of $B$ (resp. $A$).
My questions are:

can anyone offer an explicit example where the contains statement is false?
why the two have the same completion?

Update: here's my attempt for 2):
$$\widehat{B_M} = \varprojlim B_M/(MB_M)^n = \varprojlim B/M^n $$
$$= \varprojlim A[[X]]/(\mathfrak{m},X)^n = \left(\varprojlim A/(\mathfrak{m})^n\right)[[X]] =\widehat{A}[[X]],$$
where the second to the last equality holds because $A[[X]]$ is already complete with respect to $(X)-$adic topology.
Similarly, $$\widehat{A_\mathfrak{m}}= \varprojlim A_{\mathfrak{m}}/(\mathfrak{m}A_{\mathfrak{m}})^n = \varprojlim A/(\mathfrak{m}^n) = \widehat{A},$$ so $\widehat{A_\mathfrak{m}}[[X]] = \widehat{A}[[X]]$.
Update 2: In light of the above here's my attempt for 2)：setting $M=(a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_r, X)$ and $\mathfrak{m} = (a_1, a_2,\cdots, a_r)$, then by theorem 8.2 of matsumura,  $$\widehat{B_M} = \widehat{B} = B[[X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_r, X_{r+1}]]/(X_1-a_1, X_2 -a_2,\cdots, X_r-a_r, X_{r+1}-X)$$ $$ = A[[X]][[X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_r, X_{r+1}]]/(X_1-a_1, X_2 -a_2,\cdots, X_r-a_r, X_{r+1}-X),$$
$$
= A[[X, X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_r, X_{r+1}]]/(X_1-a_1, X_2 -a_2,\cdots, X_r-a_r, X_{r+1}-X)
$$
$$
= A[[X, X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_r]]/(X_1-a_1, X_2 -a_2,\cdots, X_r-a_r)
$$
and
$$\widehat{A_{\mathfrak{m}}}[[X]] =\widehat{A}[[X]] = A[[X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_r,X]]/(X_1-a_1, X_2 -a_2,\cdots, X_r-a_r)$$
so we are done.

I cannot come up with an example, but I think the problem with $A_{\mathfrak m}[[X]] \not\subset B_M$ is that in the first ring the coefficients can be arbitrary elements from $A_{\mathfrak m}$, but in $B_M$ you can only divide by a single element of $B \setminus M$, which might put restrictions on the denominators?
I came up with the following, but it might be a bit fishy. Please check rigorously!
Proposition. There is an inclusion $B_M \subset A_{\mathfrak m}[[X]]$.
Proof. The quotient $B \twoheadrightarrow B/M$ factors over $ B \twoheadrightarrow B / \mathfrak mB = A/\mathfrak m [[X]]$. The latter ring is the ring of power series over a field, so it is a local ring and the map $A/\mathfrak m [[X]] \twoheadrightarrow B/M$ has to send $X$ to $0$. Hence $$M = \mathfrak mB + (X).\tag{?}\label{eq:fishy}$$
But then $B \setminus M$ consists of all power series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i X^i$ with $a_0 \notin \mathfrak m$. But such a power series is invertible in $A_{\mathfrak m}[[X]$. $\qquad \square$
Fishy bit: Matsumura writes later in the same proof that one has \eqref{eq:fishy} only if one assumes $A$ to be complete.
